# Carousel in Tailwind CSS can not navigate to another slide when reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, carousel, tailwind-elements

I'm working on the website using React JS, Tailwind CSS. Now, I want to make a Carousel using tw-elements library. I have done all the installing, configuring following the instructions in the Tailwind Elements library document. It works perfectly find. But everytime I reload the page, I can not navigate to another slide as usual. I have tried delete the output.css file in dist folder, but it still does not work. I don't know why. Please help me with this. Thanks a BILLION!

I just copy paste code from the tailwind document, but I can not navigate to another Carousel item everytime I reload the webpage. Below is by code:

```
import { Carousel, initTE } from "tw-elements";

initTE({ Carousel });
const FeedbackSection = () => {
  return (
    // <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center border mt-40 px-3 pt-10 w-2/3 ml-40">
    //   <div className="ml-10 mb-16">
    //     <img
    //       src="/FeedbackSection/feedback-image.jpg"
    //       alt="feedback-image"
    //       loading="lazy"
    //       className="w-full"
    //     />
    //   </div>
    //   <div className="grid grid-rows-2 ml-10 items-center">
    //     <div className="text-[#1B1C1E] mt-14">
    //       <p>
    //         I cannot recommend this e-learning website enough! The quality of
    //         the content is exceptional and the instructors are knowledgeable and
    //         engaging. The interactive nature of the courses has made learning
    //         fun and enjoyable, and I have been able to apply the skills I've
    //         learned immediately in my work. The platform is user-friendly and
    //         the support team is always quick to respond to any questions or
    //         concerns. Overall, this website has been a game-changer for me and
    //         has helped me to advance my career in ways I never thought possible.
    //         I highly recommend it to anyone looking to enhance their skills and
    //         knowledge in their field.
    //       </p>
    //     </div>
    //     <div className="ml-auto mr-4 mb-10">
    //       <p>-Tho PC-</p>
    //     </div>
    //   </div>
    // </div>
    <div
      id="carouselExampleCaptions"
      class="relative"
      data-te-carousel-init
      data-te-carousel-slide
    >
      {/* <!--Carousel indicators--> */}
      <div
        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 z-[2] mx-[15%] mb-4 flex list-none justify-center p-0"
        data-te-carousel-indicators
      >
        <button
          type="button"
          data-te-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-te-slide-to="0"
          data-te-carousel-active
          class="mx-[3px] box-content h-[3px] w-[30px] flex-initial cursor-pointer border-0 border-y-[10px] border-solid border-transparent bg-white bg-clip-padding p-0 -indent-[999px] opacity-50 transition-opacity duration-[600ms] ease-[cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1.0)] motion-reduce:transition-none"
          aria-current="true"
          aria-label="Slide 1"
        ></button>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-te-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-te-slide-to="1"
          class="mx-[3px] box-content h-[3px] w-[30px] flex-initial cursor-pointer border-0 border-y-[10px] border-solid border-transparent bg-white bg-clip-padding p-0 -indent-[999px] opacity-50 transition-opacity duration-[600ms] ease-[cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1.0)] motion-reduce:transition-none"
          aria-label="Slide 2"
        ></button>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-te-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
          data-te-slide-to="2"
          class="mx-[3px] box-content h-[3px] w-[30px] flex-initial cursor-pointer border-0 border-y-[10px] border-solid border-transparent bg-white bg-clip-padding p-0 -indent-[999px] opacity-50 transition-opacity duration-[600ms] ease-[cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1.0)] motion-reduce:transition-none"
          aria-label="Slide 3"
        ></button>
      </div>

      {/* <!--Carousel items--> */}
      <div class="relative w-full overflow-hidden after:clear-both after:block after:content-['']">
        {/* <!--First item--> */}
        <div
          class="relative float-left -mr-[100%] w-full transition-transform duration-[600ms] ease-in-out motion-reduce:transition-none"
          data-te-carousel-active
          data-te-carousel-item
          style={{ backfaceVisibility: "hidden" }}
        >
          <img
            src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(15).jpg"
            class="block w-full"
            alt="..."
          />
          {/* <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center border mt-40 px-3 pt-10 w-2/3 ml-52 bg-slate-800">
            <div className="ml-10 mb-16">
              <img
                src="/FeedbackSection/feedback-image.jpg"
                alt="feedback-image"
                loading="lazy"
                className="w-full"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-rows-2 ml-10 items-center">
              <div className="text-[#1B1C1E] mt-14">
                <p>
                  I cannot recommend this e-learning website enough! The quality
                  of the content is exceptional and the instructors are
                  knowledgeable and engaging. The interactive nature of the
                  courses has made learning fun and enjoyable, and I have been
                  able to apply the skills I've learned immediately in my work.
                  The platform is user-friendly and the support team is always
                  quick to respond to any questions or concerns. Overall, this
                  website has been a game-changer for me and has helped me to
                  advance my career in ways I never thought possible. I highly
                  recommend it to anyone looking to enhance their skills and
                  knowledge in their field.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="ml-auto mr-4 mb-10">
                <p>-Tho PC-</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> */}
          <div class="absolute inset-x-[15%] bottom-5 hidden py-5 text-center text-black md:block">
            <h5 class="text-xl">First slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center border mt-40 px-3 pt-10 w-2/3 ml-52 bg-slate-800">
          <div className="ml-10 mb-16">
            <img
              src="/FeedbackSection/feedback-image.jpg"
              alt="feedback-image"
              loading="lazy"
              className="w-full"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-rows-2 ml-10 items-center">
            <div className="text-[#1B1C1E] mt-14">
              <p>
                I cannot recommend this e-learning website enough! The quality
                of the content is exceptional and the instructors are
                knowledgeable and engaging. The interactive nature of the
                courses has made learning fun and enjoyable, and I have been
                able to apply the skills I've learned immediately in my work.
                The platform is user-friendly and the support team is always
                quick to respond to any questions or concerns. Overall, this
                website has been a game-changer for me and has helped me to
                advance my career in ways I never thought possible. I highly
                recommend it to anyone looking to enhance their skills and
                knowledge in their field.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="ml-auto mr-4 mb-10">
              <p>-Tho PC-</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> */}
        {/* <!--Second item--> */}
        <div
          class="relative float-left -mr-[100%] hidden w-full transition-transform duration-[600ms] ease-in-out motion-reduce:transition-none"
          data-te-carousel-item
          style={{ backfaceVisibility: "hidden" }}
        >
          <img
            src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(22).jpg"
            class="block w-full"
            alt="..."
          />
          {/* <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center border mt-40 px-3 pt-10 w-2/3 ml-52 bg-slate-800">
            <div className="ml-10 mb-16">
              <img
                src="/FeedbackSection/feedback-image.jpg"
                alt="feedback-image"
                loading="lazy"
                className="w-full"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-rows-2 ml-10 items-center">
              <div className="text-[#1B1C1E] mt-14">
                <p>
                  I cannot recommend this e-learning website enough! The quality
                  of the content is exceptional and the instructors are
                  knowledgeable and engaging. The interactive nature of the
                  courses has made learning fun and enjoyable, and I have been
                  able to apply the skills I've learned immediately in my work.
                  The platform is user-friendly and the support team is always
                  quick to respond to any questions or concerns. Overall, this
                  website has been a game-changer for me and has helped me to
                  advance my career in ways I never thought possible. I highly
                  recommend it to anyone looking to enhance their skills and
                  knowledge in their field.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="ml-auto mr-4 mb-10">
                <p>-Tho PC-</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> */}
          <div class="absolute inset-x-[15%] bottom-5 hidden py-5 text-center text-white md:block">
            <h5 class="text-xl">Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* <!--Third item--> */}
        <div
          class="relative float-left -mr-[100%] hidden w-full transition-transform duration-[600ms] ease-in-out motion-reduce:transition-none"
          data-te-carousel-item
          style={{ backfaceVisibility: "hidden" }}
        >
          <img
            src="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(23).jpg"
            class="block w-full"
            alt="..."
          />
          {/* <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center border mt-40 px-3 pt-10 w-2/3 ml-52 bg-slate-800">
            <div className="ml-10 mb-16">
              <img
                src="/FeedbackSection/feedback-image.jpg"
                alt="feedback-image"
                loading="lazy"
                className="w-full"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-rows-2 ml-10 items-center">
              <div className="text-[#1B1C1E] mt-14">
                <p>
                  I cannot recommend this e-learning website enough! The quality
                  of the content is exceptional and the instructors are
                  knowledgeable and engaging. The interactive nature of the
                  courses has made learning fun and enjoyable, and I have been
                  able to apply the skills I've learned immediately in my work.
                  The platform is user-friendly and the support team is always
                  quick to respond to any questions or concerns. Overall, this
                  website has been a game-changer for me and has helped me to
                  advance my career in ways I never thought possible. I highly
                  recommend it to anyone looking to enhance their skills and
                  knowledge in their field.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="ml-auto mr-4 mb-10">
                <p>-Tho PC-</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> */}
          <div class="absolute inset-x-[15%] bottom-5 hidden py-5 text-center text-white md:block">
            <h5 class="text-xl">Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* <!--Carousel controls - prev item--> */}
      <button
        class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 top-0 z-[1] flex w-[15%] items-center justify-center border-0 bg-none p-0 text-center text-black opacity-50 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-[cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1.0)] hover:text-black hover:no-underline hover:opacity-90 hover:outline-none focus:text-white focus:no-underline focus:opacity-90 focus:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none"
        type="button"
        data-te-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
        data-te-slide="prev"
      >
        <span class="inline-block h-8 w-8">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="h-6 w-6"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M15.75 19.5L8.25 12l7.5-7.5"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span class="!absolute !-m-px !h-px !w-px !overflow-hidden !whitespace-nowrap !border-0 !p-0 ![clip:rect(0,0,0,0)]">
          Previous
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* <!--Carousel controls - next item--> */}
      <button
        class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 top-0 z-[1] flex w-[15%] items-center justify-center border-0 bg-none p-0 text-center text-black opacity-50 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-[cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1.0)] hover:text-black hover:no-underline hover:opacity-90 hover:outline-none focus:text-white focus:no-underline focus:opacity-90 focus:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none"
        type="button"
        data-te-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
        data-te-slide="next"
      >
        <span class="inline-block h-8 w-8">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="h-6 w-6"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M8.25 4.5l7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span class="!absolute !-m-px !h-px !w-px !overflow-hidden !whitespace-nowrap !border-0 !p-0 ![clip:rect(0,0,0,0)]">
          Next
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FeedbackSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

i copy the code and dont function me, i recomend you to do this in a component

info url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXlZCW26bto:

```js
 const [currentindex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

const prevSlide = () => {
    const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0; 
    const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? slides.length - 1 : currentIndex -1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
};

const nextSlide = () => {
    const isLastSlide = currentIndex === slides.length - 1; 
    const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
};

const goToSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(slideIndex)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).